# When is a temporary used as an initializer for a named object destroyed?

Tags: c++, temporary-objects

In "The C++ Programming Language (3rd)" p.255:

> A temporary can be used as an initializer for a const reference or a named object. For example:
>
> ```
> void g(const string&, const string&);
>
> void h(string& s1, string& s2)
> {
>    const string& s = s1+s2;
>    string ss = s1+s2;
>
>    g(s, ss);  // we can use s and ss here
> }
> ```
>
> This is fine. The temporary is destroyed when "its" reference or named object go out of scope.

Is he saying that the temporary object created by `s1+s2` is destroyed when `ss` goes out of scope?
Isn't it get destroyed as soon as it is copy initialized to `ss`?

Comment: In your last paragraph, which `s1 + s2` expression are you talking about? There are two.

Comment: @Alice Please review your previous questions and tick an answer if it answered your question.

Comment: 11 months is more than long enough to learn how to format SO posts. Please start doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only temporaries in your code are the `s1 + s2`. The first one gets bound to the const-ref `s`, and thus its lifetime is extended to that of `s`. Nothing else in your code is a temporary. In particular, neither `s` nor `ss` are temporaries, since they are manifestly *named variables*.

The second `s1 + s2` is of course also a temporary, but it dies at the end of the line, having been used to initialize `ss` only.

*Update:* Perhaps one point deserves emphasis: In the final line, `g(s, ss);`, the point is that `s` is a perfectly valid reference, and it is *not a dangling reference* as you might perhaps have expected, precisely because of the life-time extension rule for temporaries bound to const-references.

Comment: Doesn't the second `string ss = s1+s2;` also create a temporary?

Comment: But bjarne says "The temporary is destroyed when "its" reference or named object go out of scope."

Comment: The previous page also contains "Unless bound to a reference or used to initialize a named object, a temporary object is destroyed
at the end of the full expression in which it was created.". So I'm confused.

Comment: To my understanding, the temporary in this situation is also an implicit const string variable, created as actual second parameter passed to `g`, because non-const `ss` can not be passed as is. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Alice: The first temporary created by `s1 + s2` is destroyed when `s` goes out of scope. Do you agree?  Binding it to the "named reference" `s` is the crucial step. By contrast, the result of the second expression `s1 + s2` is *not* bound to a named reference, so it expires at the end of the line (the "full expression").

Comment: @Stan: I don't understand what you're asking. I don't think there's anything mysterious about the call to `g`. The point is that `s` is valid, and *not* a "dangling reference" as you might perhaps expect. Let me edit that.

Comment: Assume `g` is defined as `void g(const string& p1, const string& p2);` for clearness. Don't you think, that `p2` is assigned to a temporary (equal to `ss`), but not to `ss` directly?

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, the second expression s1 + s2 is not bound to a named refeerence but is used to inialize a named object. And to quote what bjarne says once again, "Unless bound to a reference or used to initialize a named object, a temporary object is destroyed at the end of the full expression in which it was created."

Comment: @Stan: `p2` will be a reference to the `ss` variable in the caller's scope. It's not "assigned to" anything. Rather, it is directly a reference. This is no different from any other use of references, if you think about it.

Comment: @Alice: That one's a bit more subtle. Of course the temporary lives throughout the course of the *constructor* of `ss`, but once *that* one is done, the temporary dies... *unless* the temporary is yet again bound to another const-reference within the object (which is not the case for `std::string`), if you see what I mean. If you like I can make an example.

Comment: @KerrekSB Aha I got it! So `s1+s2` is not destroyed at the end of the full expression but destroyed after the constructor of ss is executed! By "not destroyed at the end of the full expression" I misunderstood it would then not destroyed until local scope ends.

Comment: @Alice: Well, it *is* destroyed at the end of the full expression, but the constructor of `ss` finishes before that, if you will (it's another subexpression).

Comment: @KerrekSB Hmm.. Then what are the cases when a temporary object that is used to initialize named object is not destroyed at the end of the full expression?

Comment: @KerrekSB "Unless bound to a reference or used to initialize a named object, a temporary object is destroyed at the end of the full expression in which it was created." I think this means that there are two cases. 1) a temporary object is bound to a reference or 2) used to initialize a named object. And in both cases, the temporary object is not destroyed at the end of the full expression. Right? I understand the case 1. But what is the case 2? I think the code you presented belongs to the case 1.

Comment: @Alice: please disregard my last comment (deleted), which was wrong. Member const-refs can *not* extend temporaries from constructor-initializers.

Comment: @Alice have you found what the 2nd point means?

Answer (score 1):

Both are true, because two temporaries are created:

```
//creates a temporary that has its lifetime extended by the const &
const string& s = s1+s2;

//creates a temporary that is copied into ss and destroyed
string ss= s1+s2;
```